# Is there a difference between the generic bounds "Enum<T> & Foo" and "Enum<? extends Foo>"

Tags: java, generics

Are these two (valid) generic bounds:

```
<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface>
<T extends Enum<? extends MyInterface>>
```

the same?

---

Suppose I have an interface

```
interface MyInterface {
    void someMethod();
}
```

And some enums that implement it:

```
enum MyEnumA implements MyInterface {
    A, B, C;
    public void someMethod() {}
}

enum MyEnumB implements MyInterface {
    X, Y, Z;
    public void someMethod() {}
}
```

And I want to require that an implementation uses not only a `MyInterface` but also that it is an enum. The "standard" way is by an intersection bound:

```
static class MyIntersectionClass<T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> {
    void use(T t) {}
}
```

But I've discovered that this also works:

```
static class MyWildcardClass<T extends Enum<? extends MyInterface>> {
    void use(T t) {}
}
```

With the above, this compiles:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyIntersectionClass<MyEnumA> a = new MyIntersectionClass<MyEnumA>();
    a.use(MyEnumA.A);
    MyWildcardClass<MyEnumB> b = new MyWildcardClass<MyEnumB>();
    b.use(MyEnumB.X);
}
```

And the bound works as and intended and required by above for both cases.

Is there a difference between these two bounds, if so what, and is one "better" than the other?

Comment: If they are truly the sane, I'd prefer the intersection because it doesn't use wildcards, which I personally find "unclean"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific case there is no difference because Enums formal type parameter is effectively the self type. This is because one can not inherit from Enum like so:

```
class MyEnumA extends Enum<MyEnum2> {}
class MyEnumB implements MyInterface {}
```

So yes, semantically they're the same bound, but only because it's Enum.

Comment: +1 for answering the constructive part of the question and not wasting time on what the "better" syntax is, given they amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, both syntaxes achieve the same bounds - and only because of the special case of enums, where we know the `T` in `Enum<T>` must be the immediately extending `enum` type. So in restricting what `T` can be resolved to, there's no difference.

There *is* a difference in the possible usage of instances of `T`, but it's probably such a nuance that it's irrelevant. Consider that the following statement compiles in `MyIntersectionClass.use` but not `MyWildcardClass.use`:

```
T t2 = t.getDeclaringClass().newInstance();
```

Only these will compile in the latter:

```
MyInterface t2 = t.getDeclaringClass().newInstance();
Enum<? extends MyInterface> t3 = t.getDeclaringClass().newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the second one relies on the special fact that Java enums are implemented as `MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum>`, I would prefer the first one, which doesn't rely an such assumptions and states your constraints explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

They'll do the same thing, but I would say `T extends Enum<? extends MyInterface>` is a bit more standard and thus better, if only because it's more commonly and quickly recognizable. Many people don't even know about the `&` part of generics.

You could also argue that they read slightly differently. `T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface` I would read as "an enum which also happens to be a MyInterface." `T extends Enum<? extends MyInterface>` I would read as "an enum that implements MyInterface." So to that extent, it's a matter of personal preference; I prefer the latter.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but everything after the first clause is subjective and not constructive.

Comment: @PaulBellora OP's question included the question, `and is one "better" than the other`. That is inherently a subjective question, so it seems unfair to dock people for replying to the question. Your downvotes are of course yours to distribute, but I think your reasoning strains the SO [suggestions for downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), as it is not clearly or perhaps dangerously incorrect, and I'd argue it's not sloppy or no-effort-expanded either.

Comment: This is the first time I've downvoted you and I promise I thought about it. Don't take it personally :)

Comment: I'm not, don't worry. :) Nor will the 2 points ruin my new year. Difference of opinion on what SO is for, I guess.