# Static field with generic parameter extending multiple types

Tags: java, generics, enums, multiple-bounds

**What I have without any problem:**

I have multiple enums which extend the same interface:

```
interface CommonMethods {
    // some methods
}

enum E1 implements CommonMethods {
    O1, O2;
    // interface method impls
}

enum E2 implements CommonMethods {
    O3, O4;
    // interface method impls
}
```

I wanted to handle these by their common successors: `Enum` and `CommonMethods`.

So far I have methods like this:

```
static <L extends Enum<?> & CommonMethods> void m(L l) {}
```

So I can do with those enums what I want for example by calling methods from the CommonMethods interface.

**Now the problem begins:**

But I also want to store some of these in a static list field of a class like this:

```
class Test1 {
    static List<Enum<?> & CommonMethods> l = new LinkedList<>();

    static {
        l.add(E1.O1);
        l.add(E2.O3);
    }
}
```

This gives me compiler error. I have a workaround solution which to my opinion is bad:

```
class Test2 {
    static List<Enum<?>> l = new LinkedList<>();

    static {
        l.add(E1.O1);
        l.add(E2.O3);
    }

    static <L extends Enum<?> & CommonMethods> void m(L l) {}
}
```

This way I lose the constraint of the acceptable types.

**What can I do to keep the constraint?**

**Note:** This is just a dummy and not the real code with which I'm currently trying to work, so please refrain from refactoring suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the type as:

```
static <L extends Enum<? extends CommonMethods>> void m(L l) {}
```

I have struck this issue myself before and after a lot of research, I have concluded that this is identical in effect to the type intersection.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14122783/256196), and its answers discusses this topic.

Comment: I think you meant: `static <L extends Enum<? extends CommonMethods>> void m(L l) {}`. Am I right?

Comment: @Bart I think you are right. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14122783/256196) for a discussion on this topic

Comment: What if the interface is not parameterized?

Comment: @basin the interface, `CommonMethods`, is not parameterized. The question asks about an parameterized `enum`.