# interface EnhancedEnum<E extends Enum<E> & EnhancedEnum<E, V>, V>

Tags: java, java-8, enumeration

Can Any one expalin me whats the use of this interface

```
TestEnum<E extends Enum<E> & TestEnum<E, V>, V>{....}

enum test implements TestEnum<test, Integer>{....}
```

I am rookie on the enumeration can any one say what that "&" means

Comment: Yes, the `&` just means that `E` must extend both of those types.

Comment: This means that E have to be an enum and an implementation of EnhancedEnum of E (the enum) and V. V can be whatever in this case.

Comment: can you explain me what the are tyring to achieve by looking at that code

Comment: that's going to hard to explain, it depends on where you got this code - may be for a certain application this makes perfect sense...

Comment: The code you have posted does not compiled, as `test` does not implement `EnhancedEnum`, so it’s not valid as first type argument for `TestEnum`.  Well, I guess `TestEnum` and `EnhancedEnum` are supposed to be the same, but how are we supposed to tell you what the code ought to achieve from only two lines of it, which are not even copied correctly?

Comment: The `&` is a *type intersection*. Related: [Is there a difference between the generic bounds “Enum<T> & Foo” and “Enum<? extends Foo>”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122783/is-there-a-difference-between-the-generic-bounds-enumt-foo-and-enum-ext)

Comment: Nyranith your expalnation was very good